# Mule redeploy timer

Tags: mule

Whenever we run Mule server, it gives a message on Console saying "Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)". I want to change this time from 5000ms to any other value. I am using Community edition of Mule server 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure it setting *using mule.launcher.changeCheckInterval* system property. Your start command should look like:

```
bin/mule start -M-Dmule.launcher.changeCheckInterval=3000
```

Alternatively you can add this line to your conf/wrapper.conf file:

```
wrapper.java.additional.<n>=-Dmule.launcher.changeCheckInterval=3000
```

where  is the lower available number (if you didn't touch this file before is 4).

Comment: Can we set this same property in any configuration file so that we would not require to add this parameter every time we start the server.

Comment: Added that info the my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't get the last line of your answer, are you talking about setting the value of 'n' as 4 ? Also it would be very helpful if you can share the source from where I can get more info about other parameters that we can pass to mule. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, this would be the line `wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dmule.launcher.changeCheckInterval=3000`, check that there is no other  configuration starting with `wrapper.java.additional.4`. The only documentation I've found is [this](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Passing+Additional+Arguments+to+the+JVM+to+Control+Mule), or you can check [Tanuki wrapper documentation](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/props-example-config.html).

Answer (score 0):

`start -M-Dmule.launcher.changeCheckInterval=xxxx` will help.

Answer (score 0):

In wrapper.conf file add the following line:

```
wrapper.java.additional.<n>=-Dmule.launcher.changeCheckInterval=xxxx
```